# Get only audio using youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to only download the audio of a YouTube video using youtube-dl. I found that by substituting `youtube-dl -o` with `youtube-dl -x` I should get the result but that doesn't work for me since I get an error that doesn't appear if I do it with the `-q`:

> `'~/Desktop/Music/name.%(ext)s' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:~/Desktop/Music/name.%(ext)s" ) to search YouTube.`

This is my code

```
from os import system
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def titleCase(s):
    '''
    A function to convert the given song name to title case.
    The default function in Python convert the words 'the', 'and', 'of', etc.
    And I find that annoying
    '''

    l = s.split()
    str = l[0][0].upper() + l[0][1:]
    
    for word in l[1:]:
        if word not in ['in', 'the', 'for', 'of', 'a', 'at', 'an', 'is', 'and']:
            str += ' ' + word[0].upper() + word[1:]
        else:
            str += ' ' + word
    
    return str


def getVidID(song, URL):
    '''
    This function gets the ID of the Video you have to download.
    '''
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    links = []
    search = song + ' lyrics'
    searchQuery = '+'.join(search.split())
    searchURL = URL + searchQuery
    driver.get(searchURL)
    link_webelement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')
    links += [link_webelement.get_attribute('href')]
    vidID=links[0]
    return vidID

def doStuff(song):
    print("Downloading " + titleCase(song))
    URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='
    link = getVidID(song, URL)
    pathToSave = "~/Desktop/Music/"+titleCase(song)
    system("youtube-dl -o \'" + pathToSave + ".%(ext)s\' \'" + link + "\'")
    print("Downloaded " + titleCase(song) + "\n") 

def main():
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------')
    if (len(sys.argv) == 3 and (sys.argv[1] == '-i' or sys.argv[1] == '-I')):
        for song in open(sys.argv[2]).readlines():
            doStuff(song)

    else:
        for song in sys.argv[1:]:
            doStuff(song)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Any suggestion on how to solve?

Comment: Add `-a` in the system call

Comment: @inspectorG4dget where exactly?

Comment: I think he means this line: `system("youtube-dl -a -o \'" + pathToSave + ".%(ext)s\' \'" + link + "\'")`

Comment: i would try before -o

Comment: now I get ERROR: batch file -o could not be read

Comment: If I were you I would just try `system("youtube-dl -x -o \'" + pathToSave + ".%(ext)s\' \'" + link + "\'")`